# magento 2 development environment operating system

Tags: magento-2.1, environment-emulation

I am using Window OS for magento 2 development. Is it better to switch to ubuntu? Is development fast in unbuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Linux is always better for development. It also help you to get the same environment what you will have on the  live server. You will get the root user privileges and come over many restriction what other user do not have.

Comment: With virtualisation you can achieve the same with windows. I wouldn't recommend windows myself but this answer is misleading. You shouldn't develop on the machine itself anyway. And especially you shouldn't fiddle with root!